# Setup Mx record for specific host

Tags: mx-record, domain-name

I am trying to set up MX record of my domain to point to the google server. According to the google documents I should enter the following values for MX record of my domain

https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125

But the settings of the domain panel doesn't accept the values in no way, I tried to contact the hosting company to get help, but they don't provide any help and just had given me the panel for settings, I even don't know which panel it is

it look like as the following picture which may be familiar for you
http://radaut.com/layout.PNG

Anyway, my main problem is that I can't enter the settings for the MX record.

the error and the interface for entering the MX record is as the following picture

http://radaut.com/mx.PNG

the error for the google address is

```
Content must match "^([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z\@]{2,}|@)$"
```

My question is where and what should I enter to set up the MX to point to the google server.

Comment: Try lowercasing the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second screenshot above where you have tried to enter the MX Record of **ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.** Looks like it's google who has caught you out with this one.

On Google's webpage the URL for the MX Record has a **fullstop (.)** at the end of it therefore the regex from the hosting company does not expect this and is throwing it out as an invalid host!

I would suggest aspmx.l.google.com - lowercase and without the fullstop at the end :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, according to the Jenny D, I made it lowercase first, but then again encountered the problem then I removed the trailing point and it solved the problem, in fact both changes are necessary, because I had removed the trailing point before and had no success